# Is there any way to know a specific page is being visited in Django?

Tags: django

I have a page in Django that only allows one user to see at the same time. Is there any way to get this information? If I can know someone is visiting a page, I can block other requests then.

Thank you.

Comment: 'one user to see at the same time' - what do you mean?

Comment: Say a page /test/, if user A is seeing this page, then anyone else cannot see this page, request will be blocked. Only after A closes this page, then others can see it.

Comment: I dont know why you would like to do something like this, but you can create a decorator that saves a flag (in db) for each user login. So each time the user logs in, you call the decorator to update active_user flag and on logout you can reset it. So if the flag is set, you can redirect other incoming logins to some other page (Showing server busy or something). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use your database as the "referee". Make a class that inherits from a `generic.TemplateView`, override the `get` and/or `post` method, and before calling the parent, make a query to the database: if the page is being watched then dont call the parent and return a redirect to the main page.

But you may run into trouble if the one who is viewing the page switches off his computer: how will you know he's not watching anymore? You may have to implement a watchdog or something, and even then, with Chrome, the watchdog will be stopped if it's not the active tab... if I were you I would search for another way of dealing with the problem.